# Extracting Urdu Text from PDF using iTextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

When extracting Urdu (rtl language) text from pdf using iTextsharp, it's showing me mirror (reversed) text, is there any example I can follow to extract Urdu text correctly from pdf?

```
    static string ReadPdfFile(string fileName)
    {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);
            for (int page = 2; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);

                currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(currentText)));

                text.Append(currentText);
            }
            pdfReader.Close();
        }
        return text.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Persian which is an rtl language just like Urdu, I use a custom method after usual extraction with iTextSharp:

```
public string ReverseTheString(string source)
{
    try
    {
        return new string(source.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This not only makes the extracted text right-to-left but also bottom-to-top.

Comment: This doesn't work as the string extracted by iTextsharp is wrong.

Comment: Try reversing the lines by `.Split()` then '.Reverse()'.